# Mysql autoincrement error when insert a new register

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Challenge` (
  `idChallenge` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `ending` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idChallenge`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I try insert a new register:

```
insert into challenge (name, start) values ("test", now());
```

Gives me this error:

```
Error Code: 1364. Field 'id_challenge' doesn't have a default value
```

But first I don't have this column in my table and if I put it is create.

Comment: check better because Field 'id_challenge' in message error   but in your table you have  `idChallenge`    the two name are different ..

Comment: `idChallenge` or `id_challenge`?

Comment: same code works for me without any issue. Just need to change table name from  challenge to Challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are with **idChallenge**, if I change it to **idchallenge** works.

Answer (score 1):

Us must use backticks ` for reserved words.

```
insert into Challenge (`name`, `start`) values ("test", now());
```

Comment: Do you use MySQL Workbench?